# unresolved external symbol __imp____iob_func referenced in function _OpenSSLDie

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am getting below error while migrating my project from VS2008 to VS2015.

```
21>TFCLd.lib(cryptlib.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _fprintf imported in function _OpenSSLDie
21>TFCLd.lib(rsa_sign.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _fprintf imported
21>TFCLd.lib(cryptlib.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp____iob_func referenced in function _OpenSSLDie
21>TFCLd.lib(rsa_sign.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____iob_func
```

The project builds in VS2008 but with above error in VS2015. May I know what am I missing.

Comment: You are linking code that was compiled with /MT with code that was compiled with /MD.   Usually that code is located in a library.   This mistake can cause very nasty runtime errors as well, it is critical that all code that's linked together gets compiled with the same settings.  Do not use /MT.

Comment: All my codes are built with /MD. I still get the error. A

Answer (score 26):

Put this in the begin of your class header file or in stdafx.h

```
FILE _iob[] = { *stdin, *stdout, *stderr }; 
extern "C" FILE * __cdecl __iob_func(void) { return _iob; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I could build with an old binary-only library using this trick (and also linking with `legacy_stdio_definitions.lib` and it seems to work fine.

Comment: This trick solves the link error, though it produces the warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol ___iob_func imported in function ... (when building old SDL with VS2017)

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at:
http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/Compiling-OpenSSl-Project-with-Visual-Studio-2015-td59416.html

Changing line 310 of the file e_os.h in the openssl root directory from
`#      if _MSC_VER> =1300`
to 
`#      if _MSC_VER> =1300 && _MSC_VER <= 1800`
fixes the problem.

The original poster describes the cause of the problem:

> In the Visual Studio 2015 the libraries with old names were redesigned

Visual Studio 2015 is referred to as _MSC_VER == 1900.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure your libcurl.lib was compiled with the same IDE (MSVC 2015) as your application.

Answer (score 0):

Your openSSL version is outdated for VS2015. Download and install latest stable version from https://www.openssl.org/source/

Edit: How to install it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=icNn-eJif9k

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, click on the project in the Solution Explorer, and go-->Properties-->C/C++-->Code Generation-->Runtime Library.  Make the libraries and binary all the same option.